# Xamarin Android GCM Registration (502 Error)

Tags: xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, azure-web-app-service, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to Register push notificationninmy Xamarin Android project.
I get a Bad Gateway exception in the Register func of the GCMService class.
Specifically a 502 error as follows.

"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server" 
This my Register function

```
 public async void Register(Push push, IEnumerable<string> tags)
    {
        try
        {
            var templateBodyGCM = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$("+ RegistrationID+")\"}}";

            JObject templates = new JObject();
            templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
            {
                {"body", templateBodyGCM}
            };

            await push.RegisterAsync(RegistrationID, templates);
            Log.Info("Push Installation Id", push.InstallationId.ToString());


            await Task.Run(async () => await RedCheetahApp.UpdateNotificationID(RegistrationID));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

I call it in the MainActivity UI thread.
I have a Azure Cloud service which my Android App calls to register and get and get push notification. 
I've tried calling the API via PostMan but I get the same error i.e Bad Request.

Comment: Could you locate the specific code line in your `Register` function that throws the exception? Also, please provide the related core code in your Xamarin Android project and the related API to handle the registration in your Cloud service?

Comment: This is the line that throw the exception.

 await push.RegisterAsync(RegistrationID, templates);
This is the API I see that is being called 
http://redcheetah.azurewebsites.net/push/installations/b60d0147-50a7-48b6-abea-cea21f204281

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT Hi Bruce, still waiting on your reply. Thanks

Comment: I noticed that you are using azure web app. I assumed that you could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503 for troubleshooting this issue.